# Restart process by pid?

Tags: linux, process

I have pid that I want to restart,that this process start from the beginning of main , get a new pid .

How can I do that only with `pid` and not with `exec` with binary path

Answer (score 2):

As stated [here](https://superuser.com/a/907787), there is no restart signal. You must execute the process again. If this is a common thing, you should put this program in a service, or a simple loop script, so that this can be handled more organically.

However, If you want another flaky bash pipeline, here you go. This will restart a program as the executing user with no security context (so don't call this on anything you don't trust!)

```bsh
restart_pid() {
  # First we need to find the program's arguments
  SAVED_COMMAND="$(while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' f; do printf '%q ' "$f"; done < /proc/$1/cmdline)"
  # Then we need to cd into its directory so that we stay as true to the intial conditions as possible
  cd /proc/$1/cwd
  # Now kill the process
  kill $1
  # Now we can restart the process
  eval $SAVED_COMMAND
}
```

After running this, you can call `restart_pid <pid>` on any `<pid>` you have permission to send signals to.

Replace the last-but-one line with `eval $SAVED_COMMAND & disown` if you want to put the task into the background.